# Select one only one row in ant-design table component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, checkbox, antd

i'm having a problem here. It is mandatory for my project to user ant design. The link is here: https://ant.design/components/table
The component i must use is a table component. When i click on a row i must dispatch an action. The problem i'm facing is that i must check only one row.
As a result when i click on a row the checkbox in the previous row should be deselected.

I've tried to add some logic as you can see here:

````
class EvaluationDataTable extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedRowKeys: [], // Check here to configure the default column
  };

  onSelectChange = selectedRowKeys => {
    if (selectedRowKeys.length > 1) {
      const lastSelectedRowIndex = [...selectedRowKeys].pop();
      this.setState({ selectedRowKeys: lastSelectedRowIndex });
    }
    this.setState({ selectedRowKeys });
    console.log('selectedRowKeys changed: ', selectedRowKeys);
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedRowKeys } = this.state;
    const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys,
      onChange: this.onSelectChange,
    };
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }} />
        <Table
          rowSelection={rowSelection}
          columns={columnEvaluation}
          dataSource={result}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}```

But even if the selectedRow has the last checked row the no checkbox is checked. Any ideas?
````

Comment: In that case, why selectedRowKeys is declared to be an array ?

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you can configure the ant design table to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes. Since radio buttons are intended for single selection, this should solve your use case. The docs indicate that the antd Table component has a `rowSelection` prop, which takes a config object, defined [here](https://ant.design/components/table/#rowSelection). One of the options is `type`, which you can set to either `radio` or `checkbox`. You want `radio`. So you want something like:

```
<Table rowSelection={{type:'radio'}} >...</Table>
```

Comment: I had the same problem! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad i could help :)